# After removing a table from the database, doctrine shows 'MappingException'. [Symfony]

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

Good morning, I tell you my case. I **deleted a table and foreign keys** of a database that I am using in a project under **Symfony**. After importing the mapping (*XML*) and generating entities, all automatically using Symfony console; when I access any page of the project, shows me the **following exception** that can not understand:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class 'Consolidador\PanelBundle\Entity\Clients' does not exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\integracion-v2\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php:96
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\integracion-v2\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService.php(41): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::nonExistingClass('Consolidador\\Pa...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\integracion-v2\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(281): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->;getParentClasses('Consolidador\\Pa...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\integracion-v2\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(311): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses('Consolidador\\Pa...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\integracion-v2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\integracion-v2\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php on line 96
```

I checked out the **database is generated correctly** and that there is no longer any foreign key or table references in the database. Neither the **xml mapping or entity have generated**, so I do not understand why this exception.

**I hope you can help me.**

**A greeting and thanks to all.**

---

#### Edit:

- Clear the cache does not fix the error.

---

## Solved

Working under the Moon Eclipse IDE so I launched a search on the entire project looking where he used the entity that managed the deleted table. I deleted all trace of code where it appeared, I returned to generate the mapping and entities and it worked.

I'm not sure what happened but I think it was because they used it as a provider in the firewall.

THANKS TO ALL!

Comment: Did you `php app/console cache:clear`?

Comment: Yes @JovanPerovic and return this >>>
[Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException]
Class '...\Clients' does not exist. Clear the cache does not fix the error, should I have detailed in the post, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities
then 
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

If you are using any database cache like Memcache or Apc be sure to clear that by restarting their respective servers.